# Find subsets of a huge list that overlap/intersect with another large list

Tags: python, list

I wrote a Python module to find subsets of a list by checking if the items in the list overlap/intersect with items in another list. The main part of my module looks something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

There are total of 1865390 items in overalllist (items are tuple)

```
overalllist = [(8361474, 8363645), (8363182, 8363758), …, (14634342, 14634440)]
```

There are total of 608348 items in mylist

```
mylist = [(8362677, 8363216), (8414202, 8414313), …, (14634354, 14634397)]
```

Find subsets of list

```
def mysubsets(list1, list2):                       
    sublist = [(x, y) for x, y in list1 if x <= list2[1] and y >= list2[0]]                  
    return sublist
```

For my example lists given above, the first item of mylist, (8362677, 8363216), overlaps with the first two items of overalllist, [(8361474, 8363645), (8363182, 8363758)]. So for (8362677, 8363216), the subset of overalllist is [(8361474, 8363645), (8363182, 8363758)], …

Initialize an empty dictionary of list that will be populated with items from mylist as keys and subsets from overalllist as values

```
mydict = defaultdict(list)
```

Loop through each item in mylist and find subsets in overalllist and put them into mydict

```
for item in mylist:
    sublist = mysubsets(overalllist, item)
    mydict.update({item:sublist})
```

The output looks something like this

```
>>> mydict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {(14634354, 14634397): [(14634342, 14634440)], …, (8362677, 8363216): [(8361474, 8363645), (8363182, 8363758)]})
```

My script works but is extremely slow (it ran for about 18 hours). I checked the execution time using cProfile and found mysubsets() spent a lot of time:

*ncalls tottime percall cumtime percall filename:lineno(function)*
*608348 1732.827 0.003 1732.827 0.003 mymodule.py:383(mysubsets)*

I wonder if there is any most fast and efficient way to achieve my goal. Thank you.

Comment: So in each list you have a sequence of intervals, right? And can we assume that the intervals in each list have no overlaps among themselves?

Comment: Are the list sorted?

Comment: @tglaria: I sorted both of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the intervals in each list have no overlaps among themsevles, first sort each list, and then traverse both lists from beginning to end, in linear time, following this pseudo code:

```
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
while i1<len(list1) && i2<len(list2):
  if list1[i1] is to the left of list2[i2]:
    i1 += 1
  elif list2[i2] is to the left of list1[i1]:
    i2 += 1
  else // list1[i1] overlaps list2[i2]
    find all intervals from list2[i2:] that overlap with the interval list1[i1]
    i1 += 1
```

Comment: According to the description, there is overlaping in the lists.

Comment: Cool. Good luck, Lisa. If you find a mistake in my algorithm, please let me know and I will correct it. Might be useful for other people.

Comment: I checked my lists, there are some overlaps in each list among themselves. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mysubsets(list1, list2):
    len_l2 = len(list2)
    idx = 0
    sublist = []
    for x,y in list1:
        if x<=list2[idx][0]:
            if y>=list2[idx][1]:
                sublist.append((x,y))
        else:
            idx+=1
            if idx>=len_l2:
                break
    return sublist
```

Comment: Than you for your help, I will try your code and let you know the results.

Comment: This won't work with overlaping sections (in `overalllist`)

Comment: I did a quick test in a subsets of my lists, the script was still running very slow

Comment: You might want to give some (reduced) example of your data to test them and evaluate timing.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can try is a divide-and-conquer one, and this doesn't assume mutually exclusive intervals:

Fix some value X.

```
Take list1, divide it to three lists: left1, mid1, right1. 
  left1 contains all intervals that are left of x. 
  right1 contains all intervals that are right of x. 
  mid1 contains all intervals that contain x
```

The value X should be selected such that it roughly puts half of the items in left1 and the other half in right1.

```
Do the same for list2. Divide it to three lists: left2, mid2, right2.
```

Now we know that left1 has no overlaps with right2
And left2 has no overlaps with right1

```
Now, recursively find all overlaps between (left1+mid1) and (left2+mid2)
and all overlaps between (right1+mid1) and (right2+mid2)
```

The stopping condition for the recursion should be that the size of one of the lists is below some threshold.

This is not an optimal algorithm, and some overlaps here will be found more than once. But for practical purposes should be fast enough.

Comment: Thank you, Adi Levin. Is your code written in Python or some other language? I need a Python snippet and insert it into my Python module.